# Changing package content in batch

Tags: packages

I would like to know if it's safe to do batch operations in a list of package files, applying a function like this:

```
SetAttributes[packStringReplace,HoldRest]
packStringReplace[packPath_String,{replaceRule__}]:=Module[{pack},
    pack=Import[packPath,"Text"];
    pack=StringReplace[pack,{replaceRule}];
    Export[packPath,pack,"Text"]
]

packs=FileNames["*.m","/packageDirectory",∞];
packStringReplace[#,{"text1"->"text2","text3"->"text4"}]&/@packs
```

Can `Import` and `Export` change something inside pack in some unexpected way? It's safe? Or should I use `ImportString` or another `Import` equivalent? If yes, why?

### Update

As pointed by @AlbertRetey in the comments, it's safer do use:

`Export[packname,pack,"Text",CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"]`

instead of

`Export[packPath,pack,"Text"]`

Comment: I don't know of any voodoo for the "Text" format, the only thing you should be aware of is the character encoding, the default for text import/export is UTF8 and AFAIK package files typically are interpreted as pure ASCII. As that is a subset of UTF8 it probably only will make a difference if you use non-ascii characters within a package file (which one probably shouldn't do in the first place). I can't recall the details by heart, though, so you might need to look that up yourself...

Comment: @AlbertRetey nice advice. So maybe it would be better to do: `Export[packname,pack,"Text",CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"]`?

Comment: @AlbertRetey, I have made a test, and it's very important, there is an simple example: `Export["test1.txt","b \[Rule] a","Text"]`. Without use `CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"`, I get problem with \[Rule] graphic object. Tks

Comment: I'm actually surprised that my comment seems more relevant than I thought. The problem is that importing and reexporting won't create the same thing as the Mathematica-specific "ascii"-encoding of special characters is only correctly done when using the `CharacterEncoding` option for `Export`. Here is an example to play with: ExportString[ImportString["b \[Rule] a", "Text"], "Text"]. Of course this is mainly relevant if the package files are generated from a notebook with the auto save as package functionality, otherwise you probably won't expect such characters in a package file...